XSLT 2.0 - Unable to get position number of the node based on a condition
Here is a simplified version of my source XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Workers>
    <Worker>
        <ID>1234</ID>
        <Locaitons>
            <Location>
                <Primary>N</Primary>
                <Name>Oslo</Name>
            </Location>
            <Location>
                <Primary>N</Primary>
                <Name>Munich</Name>
            </Location>
            <Location>
                <Primary>Y</Primary>
                <Name>London</Name>
            </Location>
            <Location>
                <Primary>Y</Primary>
                <Name>New York</Name>
            </Location>
        </Locaitons>
    </Worker>
    <Worker>
        <ID>6789</ID>
        <Locaitons>
            <Location>
                <Primary>Y</Primary>
                <Name>Zurich</Name>
            </Location>
            <Location>
                <Primary>N</Primary>
                <Name>Brisbane</Name>
            </Location>
            <Location>
                <Primary>Y</Primary>
                <Name>Paris</Name>
            </Location>
            <Location>
                <Primary>Y</Primary>
                <Name>Toronto</Name>
            </Location>
        </Locaitons>
    </Worker>
</Workers>

Expected Output is
1234,Oslo,Default,Oslo
1234,Munich,Default,Munich
1234,London,01,,London <!-- 3rd field's position id is 01 -->
1234,New York,02,,New York <!-- 3rd field's position id is 02 -->
6789,Zurich,01,,Zurich <!-- 3rd field's position id is 01 -->
6789,Brisbane,Default,Brisbane
6789,Paris,02,,Paris <!-- 3rd field's position id is 02 -->
6789,Toronto,03,,Toronto <!-- 3rd field's position id is 03 -->

My attempt is
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"   
    xmlns:xs="    http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">
    
    <xsl:variable name="linefeed" select="'&#13;&#10;'"/>
    <xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>
    <xsl:variable name="delimiter" select="','"/>
    
    
    
    <xsl:template match="Workers">
        <xsl:for-each select="Worker/Locaitons/Location">
            <xsl:call-template name="rec"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template name="rec">
        
                 
        <xsl:value-of select="../../ID"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$delimiter"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="Name"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$delimiter"/>
        <xsl:choose> 
            <xsl:when test="Primary='Y'">               
                <xsl:value-of select="format-number(position(),'00')"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="$delimiter"/>                
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="Primary='N'">
                <xsl:text>Default</xsl:text>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise></xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
        
        <xsl:value-of select="$delimiter"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="Name"/>
        
        <xsl:value-of select="'&#10;'"/>
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>

Current Output is
1234,Oslo,Default,Oslo
1234,Munich,Default,Munich
1234,London,03,,London <!-- correct value for 3rd field should be 01 -->
1234,New York,04,,New York <!-- correct value for 3rd field should be 02 -->
6789,Zurich,05,,Zurich <!-- correct value for 3rd field should be 01 -->
6789,Brisbane,Default,Brisbane
6789,Paris,07,,Paris <!-- correct value for 3rd field should be 02 -->
6789,Toronto,08,,Toronto <!-- correct value for 3rd field should be 03 -->

The position id of the node 1,2,3 etc.. should be populated based on the value of element <Primary> = Y. I cannot add condition Primary = Y in <xsl:for-each select="Worker/Locaitons/Location[Primary='Y']"> because of several other validations that I'm performing inside rec template.
Any help is appreciated to get the desired output?
Thank you!

Use xsl:number instead of position():
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:template match="/Workers">
    <xsl:for-each select="Worker">
    <xsl:variable name="id" select="ID" />
        <xsl:for-each select="Locaitons/Location">
            <xsl:value-of select="$id"/>
            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="Name"/>
            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
            <xsl:choose> 
                <xsl:when test="Primary='Y'">   
                    <xsl:number count="Location[Primary='Y']" from="Worker" format="01"/>         
                    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:text>Default,</xsl:text>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>       
            <xsl:value-of select="Name"/>
            <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>


If it's permissible to change the internal order of the locations, you could do:
XSLT 2.0
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="Worker">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Locaitons/Location[Primary='Y']"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Locaitons/Location[Primary='N']"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Location" priority="1">
    <xsl:value-of select="../../ID"/>
    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="Name"/>
    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
    <xsl:next-match/> 
    <xsl:value-of select="Name"/>
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Location[Primary='Y']">
    <xsl:value-of select="format-number(position(), '00')"/>
    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Location[Primary='N']">
    <xsl:text>Default,</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>


This is far slower than either of the other two answers. If I were a sarcastic person I might call it "grossly inefficient"

When you call the position() function, you are finding the position of the context node within the "dynamic context" established by the earlier <xsl:for-each select="Worker/Locaitons/Location">. So the number reflects the position of the Location within the sequence of all the Location elements that are descendants of the Workers element.
It seems to me you want the position of the Location within its parent Locaitons element (that element's name is misspelled, by the way). That would be given by the expression 1 + count(preceding-sibling::Location). e.g.
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"   
    xmlns:xs="    http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">
    
    <xsl:variable name="linefeed" select="'&#13;&#10;'"/>
    <xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>
    <xsl:variable name="delimiter" select="','"/>
    
    
    
    <xsl:template match="Workers">
        <xsl:for-each select="Worker/Locaitons/Location">
            <xsl:call-template name="rec"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template name="rec">
        <xsl:value-of select="../../ID"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$delimiter"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="Name"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$delimiter"/>
        <xsl:choose> 
            <xsl:when test="Primary='Y'">               
                <xsl:value-of select="format-number(1 + count(preceding-sibling::Location[Primary='Y']),'00')"/>  
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="Primary='N'">
                <xsl:text>Default</xsl:text>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise></xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
        
        <xsl:value-of select="$delimiter"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="Name"/>
        
        <xsl:value-of select="'&#10;'"/>
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>

Personally, though, my normal practice when writing XSLT that generates plain text, is to use <xsl:sequence select="some long XPath expression"/> rather than a large number of <xsl:*> statements of one kind or another. The resulting code is usually a lot shorter, and once you're used to writing more of your logic in XPath, it is easier to read. And performance is better.
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="2.0">

   <xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

   <xsl:variable name="delimiter" select="','"/>
   
   <xsl:template match="Workers">
      <xsl:sequence select="
         string-join(
            Worker/Locaitons/Location/concat(
               ../../ID,
               $delimiter,
               Name,
               $delimiter,
               if (Primary='Y') then 
                  format-number(1 + count(preceding-sibling::*[*[1]='Y']),'00')
               else if (Primary='N') then 
                  'Default'
               else
                  (),
               $delimiter,
               Name,
               '&#10;'
            )
         )
      "/>
   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>

Result:
1234,Oslo,Default,Oslo
1234,Munich,Default,Munich
1234,London,01,London
1234,New York,02,New York
6789,Zurich,01,Zurich
6789,Brisbane,Default,Brisbane
6789,Paris,02,Paris
6789,Toronto,03,Toronto


I don't think this produces the wanted result (only some locations need to be counted). More importantly, repeated counting of preceding siblings is grossly inefficient.

I added the [Primary='Y'] predicate and included the full stylesheet and result.

My testing here shows that the XPath-heavy version I've added is the most performant of the 4 suggestions currently on offer, though in fact there's not all that much between them
